# New photo rules by Google

Tags: permissions, sdk, photo

I just saw somewhere that Google may be enforcing a policy to block apps from accessing photos that were not taken by the app.  Has anyone else seen this? I can't find the original announcement, but I have had some users complaining of not being able to use my app to open other photos.

SDK less than 33 seems to work fine, but Google requires 33.

Found the announcement. This is on **Preview: Permissions and APIs that Access Sensitive Information**
For a more privacy preserving experience for users, we’re introducing the Photo and Video Permissions policy to reduce the number of apps permitted to request broad photo/video permissions (READ_MEDIA_IMAGES and READ_MEDIA_VIDEO). Apps may only access photos and videos for purposes directly related to app functionality. Apps that have a one-time or infrequent need to access these files are requested to use a system picker, such as the Android photo picker. (effective August 31, 2024)

Fixed the app with a READ_MEDIA_IMAGES ask for permission.